# PDO connect not displaying errors

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

So I'm trying to connect to a DB with PDO. I was able to do this earlier today, but now I'm not sure if its working because when I enter wrong credentials I get errors. Here's my code

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$host = "localhost";
$pass = "root";
$dbname = "users";
$user = "root";

try{
    $con->pdo->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING );
    $con = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass);

 }
 catch(PDOException $e){
    echo $->getMessage();
 }
```

When I run any other script they work fine. Anyone see any errors? Also this is what I see in my dev tools when running it. This *only* happens with the code above.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your default setting of `display_errors` is 0. And you have fatal error. So your code have not been executed and `display_errors` was not changed, hence you have not recieved error message. You could change your ini settings to display errors.

Or even better - use ide with error highlighting.

You should rewrite your code.

```
try{
    $con = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass); // change order
    $con->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION ); // change to exception, remove pdo->
 }
 catch(PDOException $e){
    echo $e->getMessage(); // <- fixed
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want it throw [exceptions](http://www.php.net//manual/en/pdo.setattribute.php), you need to enable to tell it do that.

```
$con->pdo->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
```

Furthermore, try setting `error_reporting(-1)` to enable them all.

```
catch(PDOException $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Just fixed it. And still the same issue.